# emacs 28.1 'parse-time-weekdays' - weekdays configuration doesn't working

Tags: org-mode, calendar

Before Emacs 28.1 (Linux) I used:

```
(eval-after-load 'parse-time
  '(progn
     (setq parse-time-weekdays (nconc parse-time-weekdays
      '(("so" . 0) ("mo" . 1) ("di" . 2) ("mi" . 3) ("do" . 4) ("fr" . 5) ("sa" . 6)))))
```

which gives german weekdays when entering org-mode dates, like *<2022-08-21 So>*, now I'am getting *<2022-08-21 Sun>* (Org mode version 9.6).

Any clues?

Comment: What locale are you running Emacs in?

Comment: same as with emacs 27, `cat /proc/<pid>/environ` gives:
`LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=de_DE`
I 've tried also `LC_TIME`, `LC_ALL` and emacs variable `system-time-locale` without success.